# Significance of multi factor interactions in linear regression

Tags: regression, interaction, linear

I was told by a professor of a stats course last year (who I can't now contact), that it is unlikely to find statistically significant interaction terms using more than three factors.

Is this true?

If so, is there a reference to a journal/conference paper that I can cite?

Does the answer change depending on the type of data that is being analysed? (People vs chemical reaction vs algorithm execution times, etc)
I have already looked through scholar.google.com, without much luck.

Comment: I would argue that it is not necessarily hard to find significant 3-way interaction terms, I think the biggest reason they are not used more is because the interpretation is difficult. See http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2008/ST-139.pdf .

Comment: @k6adams An interesting article, thanks. I'm still holding out for a "significant" citation. Also, its above three factors that I'm primarily interested in.